# Add padding around image in PDF document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a series of images back-to-back and I would like them to be further separated when I knit a PDF file than whatever the default is.

For example, in the following document:

````
 ---
title: "Image Test"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r echo = FALSE, fig.height=3}
vec1 <- rnorm(100)
vec2 <- rnorm(100)

plot(vec1)

plot(vec2)
```
````

I would like to control the distance between the plots. The only thing I've found so far is to keep intermediate TeX and put in newlines manually.

Comment: Can you give us a basic knitr document w/ some simple code to start from?

Comment: Absolutely! See above.

Comment: you could use `par(mar-...)` to increase the margins of your plots

Answer (score 0):

You could put the two plots in separate chunks and put LaTeX \newline in between